# Embed video in application (Linphone C API)

Tags: c, api, video, linphone

I'm trying to embed video in desktop application using `Linphone C API`.
By default, if to use samples from [tutorial](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__basic__call__tutorials.html) during call video window appears in separate window. 
Could you please tell me, how to insert this video in my desktop application?
All I found seems helpful in [Linphone C API reference](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/modules.html), function:

[`linphone_core_set_native_video_window_id`](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__media__parameters.html#ga91aed51e248d68371198ee4071828702)

Description:

```
Set the native video window id where the video is to be displayed.
For MacOS, Linux, Windows: if not set or zero the core will create 
its own window, unless the special id -1 is given.
```

Could it be helpful? How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function from linphone SDK to get window handle:

```
void *get_native_handle(GdkWindow *gdkw){
#ifdef GDK_WINDOWING_X11
    return (void *)GDK_WINDOW_XID(gdkw);
#elif defined(WIN32)
    return (void *)GDK_WINDOW_HWND(gdkw);
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
    return (void *)gdk_quartz_window_get_nsview(gdkw);
#endif
    g_warning("No way to get the native handle from gdk window");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is few lines of code:

```
GtkWidget *video_window, *window;
window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
video_window = gtk_drawing_area_new();
unsigned long *videoID;
videoID = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
*videoID = get_native_handle(gtk_widget_get_window(video_window));
linphone_core_set_native_video_window_id(lc, *videoID);
```

Worked for me!